# Link to mobile not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, broken-link

There is a link saying "mobile" at the bottom of stackoverflow page. The link is not working. It is just showing "about" page. Could anyone confirm this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Certain pages on our sites don't have a mobile equivalent - the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is one of those.

Click on the home page after clicking on mobile and you'll see what is intended for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the link works for me on the home page.

[image: Screenshot of the mobile Stack Overflow page]

[As Jarrod points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121016/162705), other pages don't have a mobile theme. It looks like these include **chat**, **about**, **faq**, **blog**, and **legal**.